# Setting default anchor in jquery tools scrollable

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools, scrollable

I am using jquery tools scrollable to create a 3 page site with a panoramic background (each background representing a page). I need the homepage to show as default. My current order is projects, home and contact and projects shows as default. I have tried using index.html#home but it doesn't work. I am using horizontal scrolling.

My navigation menu is

```
<li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
```

and my page code is:

```
<div id="browsable" class="scrollable"> 
<div class="projects"> ... </div>
<div class="home"> ... </div>
<div class="contact"> ... </div>
```

and this bit does my scrolling

```
$("#browsable").scrollable().navigator();
```

Comment: jQuery Tools has been neglected by the developer for nearly 2 years.  The last release was only to fix a few incompatibilities with newer versions of jQuery.  The next release (which has been promised for many months), will render your present code totally obsolete, as per the developer.  I strongly recommend a more popular, up to date and compliant jQuery plugin for any new project.

Comment: My mistake those should read #projects, #home and #contact

Answer (score 0):

Defining links by `href-"#projects"` is wrong.  Use as equals to (=) sign for that purpose.

```
<li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
```

Your `index.html#home` should work now.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the html error. My code uses href="..." It doesn't work appending the URL with index.html#home

Comment: @BenMatewe, Can you create a fiddle for this?